# Why phase is the position of the waveform relative to time 0

Tags: signal, frequency, wave

I was reading a book which says:

Phase  describes  the  position of the waveform  relative  to  time 0. It indicates the status of the first cycle. 
and below is a picture

[image]

I am a little bit confused. According to the picture, at time 0, the waveform is just a point. Later it starts to form a waveform shape, so how come a waveform is relative to a point at time 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition:

> **waveform**
>   /ˈweɪvfɔːm/
>   *noun* PHYSICS
>   a curve showing the shape of a wave **at a given time**.
>    [Oxford Dictionaries](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/waveform).

I think that Oxford have it slightly wrong and that it should be "a curve showing the shape of its graph as a function of time". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveform) is better.

The waveform represents the variation in a value with respect to time. This could be a voltage (electrical), a height (wave on the sea), pressure (sound), etc. and simply shows the instantaneous value at any point on the time axis.

> According to the picture, at time 0, the waveform is just a point.

Not quite. We can deduce two things from the graph:

- At *t* = 0 the amplitude is zero.
- At *t* = 0 the amplitude is rising at a rate given by the slope of the curve at that point.

> Later it starts to form a waveform shape, so how come a waveform is relative to a point at time 0?

The diagram is comparing the relative phase of three different waves of the same frequency with a periodic time of *T*.

- The first has been taken as reference and *t* = 0 has, for convenience, been chosen as the point where the wave crosses the time axis. (It's easy to visually see and compare the intersection of the curve with the axis.)
- The second is is at maximum at *t* = 0. By sketching in the dotted section we can see that it crossed the time axis earlier than the first trace and is leading the first by 90° or *T*/4.
- The third trace is leading by 180° or *T*/4.

> ... so how come a waveform is relative to a point at time 0?

Typically *t* = 0 is just chosen for convenience to make the illustration clear.

Answer (score 0):

"Waveform" describes the whole thing, and not a "shot picture" at some point in time t.

So, a system overall has a waveform, and at any point in time that means that the signal has a value (that's what you meant when you said "it's just a point").

Answer (score 0):

One can **only** define a phase of a waveworm **relative to** another (base) waveform (not directly relative to t=0).
The base waveform is considered at a convinient point (where it cuts the time axis) or a random point in time which is then called t=0.
The other waveforms are seen with respect to this waveform and the phase is determined by the shift seen from t=0.

In your question, the base waveform is a sine, so, \$A \sin(2\pi f t) \$. So, the first shown waveform has no phase delay.
Were the base waveform a cosine, then the second waveform would have no phase delay.